# how to equate with for loop counter in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have {{get_url}} from context, and a JSON object (as dict).

All I want is when JSON.entry.counter == {{get_url}}, it should display JSON.entry.content

I have done this in the following way:

```
{% for aEntry in feed.entries %}
{% ifequal forloop.counter get_url %}
<p>{{aEntry.content}}</p>
{% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

And this is not working.. I unable to equate..
what's the error and how to fix it

Comment: `forloop.counter` is an integer, whats in `get_url`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `{% if forloop.counter == get_url %}`.

But if your syntax is correct, and this is not working, I recommend checking if variables are correct with [Django debug toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar).

Answer (score 2):

Are you considering that `forloop.counter` starts at `1`, not `0`? For 0-indexed results, use `forloop.counter0`.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `get_url` is probably a string, whereas your loop counter will be an integer. In your context you can cast the value of `get_url` to an `int`